# Prior knowledge on attributes?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, vtd-xml

I am currently looking to integrate `VTD-XML` in to our project (as a replacement of a Stax based system).

Our xml files are mostly structured like this:

```
<header>
  <entry1 timestamp="0"/>
  <entry2 timestamp="1"/>
  <entry1 timestamp="2"/>
  <entry2 timestamp="3"/>
</header>
```

Is there a way to get `VTD-XML` to recognize that the timestamps are strictly ordered and to abort a xpath query like `/header/*[@timestamp < 2]` early?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not that i'm aware of. But you could select the last node:

```
/header/*[@timestamp = 2]
```

and then use selectPrecedingNode()

Comment: Hmm ... no that's not what I meant. I want to iterate every entry from x to y (`/header/*[@ts > x and @ts < y]`). But as the program has no idea that the timestamps are ordered it has to check every following timestamp too.

Comment: So perhaps I didn't understand your problem: VTD-XML, with the autopilot evalXPath just puts a cursor on the corresponding nodes. Then you just have to iterate on the nodes with the PrecedingNode and break out of the iteration when it reaches the timestamp you want?

Comment: Sure I could do that, but actually `evalXPath` will return -1 when there are no more entries. I was hoping that there'd be a way to short circuit that with prior knowledge :)

Comment: if you : first evalXPath on a timestamp max value, and then iterate with selectPrecedingNode, the only way evalXPath will return -1 is if you have absolutly no entries with a correct timestamp. It does not look like a big penalty. Whatever... If you find some xpath miracle, let us know.

Comment: I'll just accept the answer. Maybe don't using xpath and checking the attributes myself is an ok alternative.

Comment: This is a clever solution.